# PHP strings space wrapping

Tags: php, file, space, word-wrap

I am using a TAB delimited file to import data in MySQL with PHP. My problem is whenever i display large strings (which are imported from Tab delimited files ONLY) which have spaces in them they won't wrap inside DIV,table cells e.t.c.

For example a big name like:

**Mario Mark Le Blanc De Cooper VII**

won't wrap inside a small DIV or table cell and instead will overflow and overlap nearby areas like other table cells. The wrapping problem occurs ONLY with data inserted from the tab delimited file.

Now the weird thing is after i go to PHPMyAdmin and manually remove all its spaces and re-add them, the word **WILL** wrap normally. I tried to import data from both ANSI and UTF8 encoded files but nothing changed.

I checked the ASCII code of the space character and it is indeed space.
I also tried **str_replace** to replace the string's spaces with new spaces but the problem persists

Comment: If you look at the mark-up of your HTML are there any `&nbsp;` characters in it? Like.. `Mario&nbsp;Mark&nbsp;Le&nbsp;Blanc&nbsp;De &nbsp;Cooper&nbsp;VII`

Comment: @FDL that was the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using `preg_replace` ? This might help you:

```
$yournewvariable= preg_replace('/\s+/','',$youroldvariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = 'Mario Mark Le Blanc De Cooper VII';

$text = str_replace("\t", '', $string);
echo $text;
```

Try removing the actual tabs in the code.

Comment: The string Mario Mark Le Blanc De Cooper VII doesn't have any tabs to replace. It has spaces between the words. The thing is the line (group of words) acts like one word which is weird.